# Existence of a countable family of pairwise non-similar partial orders with $2^c$ maximal elements, and no minimal elements

Tags: order-theory

Give an example (if exists) for a countable family of partially ordered sets such that:

a) they are non-similar in pairs (explained under the question)

b) each set has exactly $2^c$ maximal elements and $0$ minimal elements.

If such family of sets doesn't exist, prove it.

Two partially ordered sets are similar if there exists a similarity function $f$. Similarity function is a bijection such that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ order-preserving.

I seriously can't even conclude whether such family exists, so I would appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I forgot to mention that there needs to be $\textbf{exactly}$ $2^c$ maximal elements.

Comment: For an easier problem, how about if you instead wanted there to be $0$ maximal elements and $0$ minimal elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a decreasing sequence of elements, namely a copy of $\Bbb{Z\setminus N}$, or a reverse copy of $\Bbb N$. Let us denote by $\omega^*$ this partial order.

Now consider $n\times\omega^*$, which is a consecutive chain of $n$ copies of $\omega^*$. It has a maximal element, yes, but no minimal element.

What happens when you take $n\neq m$ and consider $2^c$ disjoint copies of $n\times\omega^*$ and $2^c$ copies of $m\times\omega^*$? Are they isomorphic?

Comment: Could you please explain with some more details? I'm not really sure if I understand what you're saying.

Comment: How about you tell me what you think I mean, and then I can clarify on the necessary points.

Comment: Of course. I understand how you defined $\omega^*$. Is a partial order induced by the order of numbers in $\mathbb{N}$?
If yes,  I understand that $n\times\omega^*$ has a maximal element, $(n, \omega^*)$, if I'm correct.
What I don't get is how do you mean to consider $2^c$ disjoint coipes of $n\times\omega^*$ and $m\times\omega^*$? How to treat more copies of $n\times\omega^*$? Do I need to compare them in the given order?

Comment: Taking $I$ disjoint copies of some order $P$ means that we consider $I\times P$ with the order defined as $(i,p)\leq (j,q)$ if and only if $i=j$ and $p\leq_P q$. Here $I$ is some set of size $2^c$ and $P$ is $n\times\omega^*$ for some $n$.

Comment: Thank you! This is great!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Why is it that they're not isomporhic? Isn't the cardinality equal?

Comment: @MakeTheTrumpetsBlow: It's not about cardinality. It's about order type. How many elements does $n\times\omega^*$ have which do not have a successor element?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I guess $n$?  Interesting question and answer though!

Comment: @MakeTheTrumpetsBlow: Don't guess, prove.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Will try! Just, to be sure by $n \times \omega$ you mean as in an n-times Cartesian product with a partial set on each coordinate? Or something different, I haven't seen this notation until now.

Comment: @MakeTheTrumpetsBlow: Yes, it is the lexicographic product of $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ with its usual ordering and $\omega^*$.